# java:34: error: cannot find symbol in flutter GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M215F in debug mode...
C:\DART PROJECT\pdf scanner\noturk_docs\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ImagePickerPlugin
  location: package io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

these are the error i got when i tried to run without debugging.i tried many options but none of it is working

Comment: Please specify what exactly you have tried so far. That could help to narrow the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try running these,

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```